# Memory error on raspberry pi in for loop taking dark frame images with Picamera

Tags: numpy, image-processing, raspberry-pi

ok, so I'm trying to take 100 dark frames with the picamera. exposure_mode is set to "off" and the shutter speed is set at 5 milseconds I'm doing this in a fairly straightforward for loop:

```
for i in range(NUM_DARK_FRAMES):
  print ('loop %s' % (i+1))
  camera.capture(output, 'jpeg', bayer=True )
  arr = output.array
  print ('saving array')
  numpy.save('%sDarkFrame_%s' % (dark_frames_path, i+1), arr)
  gc.collect()
```

from the print statements I'm seeing that it's getting to loop 38, and returns a memoryerror. I added the explicit garbage collect because it helped someone else with a similar issue, to no avail. any ideas?

Comment: You don't include the full code (e.g. what is a `camera` object?). It's possible that the `camera` is saving some state between iterations of the loop. If there's no option to turn caching off, try creating a new `camera` each iteration of the loop.

Comment: thanks, your cache comment got me pointed in the right direction, I found out it was a limitation of the Pi/picamera and rewrote it to redeclare the camera every 25 loops(outer for loop of 4, inner loop of 25).

Comment: Cool, you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is due to a limitation of the Raspberry Pi, in the advanced recipes pasted below, they suggest using streaming to capture a series of images, but this doesn't work with jpeg format, which is necessary for raw bayer data captures:

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html

I solved this by making an outer for loop that controls the camera instantiation and an inner loop that runs for 25 images. this clears the cache and prevents the problem from arising (it usually occurred between loop 37-39).